# Warning message in laravel

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I've got a warning message in laravel in my project. How can i resolve it?

> Warning:
>   require(C:\xampp\htdocs\****\*****\vendor\composer/../../app/Http/Helpers/CustomHelper.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\*********\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line
>   66
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\****\*****\vendor\composer/../../app/Http/Helpers/CustomHelper.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\****\*****\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line
>   66

Comment: why whats the problem @LeoinstanceofKelmendi

Comment: run composer dump-autoload

Comment: how can i dump-autoload can u guide me please @LeoinstanceofKelmendi

Comment: Read how to property install a Laravel project.

Answer (score 0):

Try `composer dump-autoload`
 to reload dependencies. You might need to run `composer update`  before that